# My Python Module Just Will Not Work

Tags: python

I Am Not A Pro, I Have Not Been Programing For Long But Why Doesn't This Work?

```
door = input("I Have Found A Haunted House,Should I Go In?")

if door == "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
    print("Ok! I Am Going In")

else:
    print("What?")


while door == "no" or "No" or "NO":
    print("Awwh Thats A Shame, I Was Getting Excited")
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Offtopic: I think you have ".title()" virus on your computer... ;)

Comment: Do you really want to print that last message infinitely if the user enters "no"?

Comment: For reference: programming does not work like spoken language with conjunctions. You *must* explicitly say what each clause/condition applies to. "If I go to the store and buy milk" must be "If I go to the store and I buy milk".

Comment: "Not working" does **not** have a meaning. Either 1) the program raises an exception and you should post the **full** traceback, or 2) it gives an unexpected output, and you should post the output you get *and* the output you'd expect, or 3) the program gets stuck, which you didn't say. It'd be even better to provide a *minimal* working example that demonstrates the problem instead of the whole program. Next time be sure to provide this information because in this case the error was obvious, in other cases the best people *cannot* answer you without *at least* such information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, this is a very common mistake.

You need to use [`in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) here:

```
if door in ("yes", "Yes", "YES"):
```

Or, even better, [`str.lower`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower):

```
if door.lower() == "yes":
```

The reason for this is that Python evaluates non-empty strings as being `True`.  So, your code is actually being interpreted like this:

```
if (door == "yes") or ("Yes") or ("YES"):
#    True/False        True       True
```

As you can see, this if-statement will *always* pass.